# How to manually add a root view controller arrow after new a storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I was just created a new storyboard for test, rather than bother the main storyboard.
so when if I was testing, I would like to use the new storyboard I can managed add some view controllers, and I can start the storyboard as well as one of the controller in source code, but how to make a view controller in the storyboard, as there isn't the arrow as the main one!

[image: how to make this view controller the root view controller?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean how can you designate a view controller as the storyboard's root view controller? Select the view controller, open the Attributes Inspector, and select `Is Initial View Controller`.

[image: Attributes Inspector]

Answer (score 4):

Select the view controller and in the Attributes Inspector, check the "Is Initial View Controller" checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

by clicker on is initial view controller at attribute Inspector it will give connection to that viewcontroller